# decode in oracle convert to postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, database-migration

I want to convert the decode function from oracle to postgres command.
example oracle command: ***select decode(p.statusgeometry,1,'pass','fail') as status***

please help & guidance

Comment: select (case p.statusgeometry when 1 then 'pass' else 'fail' end) as status

Answer (score 2):

The `decode` equivalent is `CASE`:

```
WITH p (statusgeometry) AS (VALUES (1),(2))

SELECT 
  CASE statusgeometry
    WHEN 1 THEN 'pass'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'fail'
  END,
  -- The following syntax is useful in case you need to do  "something"  
  -- with the columns depending on the condition, e.g lower(), upper(), etc..
  CASE 
    WHEN statusgeometry = 1 THEN 'pass'
    WHEN statusgeometry = 2 THEN 'fail'
  END
FROM p;

 case | case 
------+------
 pass | pass
 fail | fail
(2 rows)
```