# Convert decode and Instr to postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration

I am migrating oracle to aurora postgres on rds. I came across below code snippt ,

`SELECT decode(Instr(A.TECH_TYPE,'ATM'),1,Decode(y.UMAT_ID,Null,Decode(A.BANDWIDTH_FORECAST,Null,0,A.BANDWIDTH_FORECAST),0), Decode(x.Number_Forecast,Null,Decode(A.BANDWIDTH_FORECAST,Null,0,A.BANDWIDTH_FORECAST),x.Number_Forecast)) As Forecas FROM TABLE A , TABLE X.`

How do i convert decode and Instr with the above query to postgres compactable form ?

Comment: You probably need case to replace decode and position to replace  instr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [decode in oracle convert to postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68496679/decode-in-oracle-convert-to-postgres)

Comment: `decode` is typically done with `case .. when .. end`  in standard SQL. And `instr()` would probably match to `strpos()` in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

The only `instr` is checking the string starts with 'ATM' so just use like instead.

`decode` can be replaced as `case` statements.

That said, this code could be made much easier to read (in both Oracle and Postgres) by something like this (not tested)

```
select 
  case when A.TECH_TYPE like 'ATM%' then
            case when y.UMAT_ID is null then coallesce(A.BANDWIDTH_FORECAST,0) else 0 end
       else case when x.Number_Forecast is null then coallesce(A.BANDWIDTH_FORECAST,0) else x.Number_Forecast end
  end as Forecas
FROM TABLE A , TABLE X
```

this won't work though as you have a y alias in your select but this should give you the idea.

If you need `instr` for anything other then the start of the string then `strpos` is probably what you need